# Cant get post_save to work in Django

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I read the `django docs` about `signals` and wrote this piece of code for my model `Car` :

```
@receiver(request_finished)
def signal_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'Save Signal received'


@receiver(post_save, sender=Car)
def signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    pass


request_finished(signal_callback, sender=car, dispatch_url="Unique save id")
```

But the problem is, that when I fire up my server, and just open up the admin, I get a lot of `'Save Signal received'` in my terminal. What I am wondering about is I have restricted the `signal_handler` to `post_save` only. But still, without even saving anything, the message shows up a lot of times. I dont understand this.

Note : I will be honest. I understood parts of it, not everything from the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simpler way to bind [`post_save` signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from myapp.models import Car

def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'the object is now saved.'
    car = kwargs['instance'] #now i have access to the object

post_save.connect(do_something, sender=Car)
```

The signal [`request finished`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#request-finished) gets called **every** time a HTTP request is made, which is a hog.

Answer (score 2):

You binded `request_finished` signal to `signal_callback`. Remove(or comment out) `signal_callback`, and change `signal_handler` as follow.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Car)
def signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'Save signal received'
```

Comment: and then I should bind `request_finished` with `signal_handler` ?

Comment: then what about the method thats supposed to send the signal?

Comment: `signal_handler` is called when `Car.objects.create(...)` or `Car(...).save()` is called.

Comment: yeah that works. but I don't grasp it very well. Is it like `request_finished` sending the signal when its saved and `signal_handler` catching it?

Comment: `request_finished` is not relevant to save. request_finished signal is fired when http request is handled.

Comment: no, the `request_finished` signal is fired when the model is done saving itself not when the http request is handled.

Comment: @limelights, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished

Comment: @falsetru My fault, I read the question too fast. You are 100% correct!

Comment: @falsetru so when the http request is complete, it checks whether its a `save` or not, and then calls the `signal_handler`. Is this the process?

Comment: @falsetru hey I've done what you have said. So when `signal_handler` is called, the object is supposed to be `saved` right. I am running the code in `pdb` and upon inspecting, I see that the `many-to-many` element isnt getting saved. In the `next save` operation of the "same object", the previous data appears and the new data that has been added, doesnt. Any specific reason you think?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta, Please post another question with **code**.

Comment: @falsetru The new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263780/many-to-many-field-not-shown-in-object-while-using-signals-to-detect-save-operat