# Many to many field not shown in object while using signals to detect save operation in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-signals

This is a follow up question to : [Cant get post_save to work in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257910/cant-get-post-save-to-work-in-django/17259611?noredirect=1#17259611)

**My models are :**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    some other attributes of Car
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    ...
    Some other attributes of Person
    ...


class License(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    ...
    Other attributes of License
    ...
```

**Signal handler:**

```
def signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'Person saved!'
    generate_license()

post_save.connect(signal_handler, sender=Person, dispatch_uid="Unique person")
```

**The intent:**  When an instance of Person is created, I want to generate a License object. So I filter out the last tuple that was added into License and then use its contents to generate a License instance.

```
def generate_license():
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    man = Person.objects.filter().order_by('-time_added')[:1][0] # Restricting the filter to one query and then taking the value at the 0th index. order_by '-time_added' gives the latest tuple at the top.
    license = License.objects.create(...Info about car, person...)
```

**The Error:**

An example:
Say `Car` has 3 instances:

1. BMW
2. FERRARI
3. LAMBORGHINI

Now when I add an instance of Person from the admin, example:

`per` be an instance with `car = BMW, FERRARI` and `name = Bob`
When I click `save` in admin, the `set_trace()` starts. So after the query in `generate_license` :

In `pdb`, when the query executes, I try printing out `per.car.all()` but it gives me `[]` and when I try printing out `per.name`, it does print out `Bob`. So I am not really getting as to how `per.name` is saved and `per.car` isnt.

Also, when the request is completed, that is I have pressed `c` in `pdb`, I again click on save for the same instance, this time it reads the `per.car.all()` perfectly while if before saving, I added `LAMBORGHINI`, it only shows up `BMW` and `FERRARI`. So what I guess is happening is that the `many-to-many` field is coming a request late. Although I can't point out the reason for this. Need some help. Am I missing something?

**Question:** Is there a specific way to identify an `update signal` from a `create signal`? I mean I do not want to generate a new `License` every time a data is updated. A new `License` will only generate when the data has been created. So, how to distinguish between `update` and `save` signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post_save` does not work on m2m fields. You have to use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

Something like this:

```
def my_m2m_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    action = kwargs.get('action')
    if action == 'post_add':
        print 'post_add is activated on m2m'

signals.m2m_changed.connect(my_m2m_signal, sender=Person.car.through)
```

Comment: Oh yes. I had read this in django-docs. But it seems I over looked it. :(

Comment: So, if I send a `m2m_changed` how do I detect that both `post_save` and `m2m_changed` has been received? Because only then I can generate a License instance.

Comment: i just updated the answer.. You need to listen to the `action` attribute that is sent into the signal

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5469114/1628832 It gives a good idea of how m2m changed is implemented

Comment: so does a change in m2m gurantee that other fields are saved?

Comment: It gets triggered once m2m fields are successfully saved

Comment: Okay. So what about the 2nd part. How to detect an update from a create?

Comment: There is a parameter `created` set to True or False whether it was created or not

Comment: So post_save has that. m2m_changed doesnt have it. so I will have to use both right?

Comment: Hmm, so can you suggest an idea as to how to do it? should I like do something like call a `post_save.connect()` and the method that receives it calls a `m2m_changed.connect()` ? Is this viable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32241/discussion-between-indradhanush-gupta-and-karthikr)